# Pivot/Transpose in hive

Tags: sql, hive, pivot, transpose

I want to calculate sum and grouby using id and convert id as column header and sum as value.

For example

```
ID|amount
1|100
1|200
2|100
```

Final output

```
1|2
300|100
```

Any pointer:
I have tried below query

```
select * from table pivot( sum(amount) for id in ("666","111"))
```

but getting below error and I don't see if I missed any EOF

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: missing EOF at '(' near 'PIVOT'; line 1 pos 63
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:318)
```

Comment: do you have a limited number of id's?

Comment: The attempted query does not match the data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as Hive doesn't support `pivot`.

```
select sum(case when id='111' then amount else 0 end),sum(case when id='666' then amount else 0 end)
from tbl
```

`id='111'` returns a `boolean` which is converted to `int` for summation.

This assumes there are a limited number of id's in the table.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.it given occurrences like below  c1-> 2 and C2->1 (can't format comment here) . In real case I will be using date to group by.so at max I can have 30 id's

Comment: I ran query as above  it doesn't give aggregated SUM of amount column.It gives occurrence of value

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for the PIVOT clause in Oracle/PLSQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT column1, column2
  FROM tables
  WHERE conditions
)
PIVOT 
(
  aggregate_function(column2)
  FOR column2
  IN ( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n) | subquery
)
ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ];
```

including the semicolon. give it re-try and let us know.

Comment: the question is about `Hive`. Not `Oracle`.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala hive was an oracle product not?!

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala you are right, I was confused with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/beehive/downloads/index.html